# Can't figure out why the overleaf project can't show up figures in the PDF(This question has on my mind for a week)

Tags: floats

Thank you for the advice.
These are some of my code, btw, all of the figure can't be seen when I edit the code but they are all just fine before I edit, I changed some of my package.

[image]

```
\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{subfig} % for subfigures

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf,small},textfont={it,small}}

\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont={bf,small},textfont={it,small},
subrefformat=parens} %<-----designing subcaption

\newcommand{\myfigref}[2]{~\ref{#1}.\subref{#2}}% <---- a new macro for referring to a subfigure

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}  
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat[First picture]{\label{fig:mdleft}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{411.png}}}\hfill
\subfloat[Second picture]{\label{fig:mdright}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{412.png}}}
\caption{}
\label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example. This is a really long code snippet. Also, could you state your question at the beginning of your post?

Comment: you have posted a _lot_ of code but no one can run the example as it references images that we do not have. try to make a small self contained example (simply delete all the words and packages not needed to show the problem) and use `example-image` as the image so we can test it. Also show your log file which should show why the images are not appearing.

Comment: sorry, after your edit the document can not be run at all. It is  not a complete document and even if we guess what `\documentclass`  to add it references images that we do not have, and you have not shown the log file to show what errors or warnings you get. LaTeX will not fail to show the image without giving a warning in the log. As requested above please make a _complete_ document that shows the problem and uses `example-image` which is a test image made available for these sorts of tests.